# The integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin 2\theta ~ \mbox{erf}(\sin \theta)~ \mbox{erf}(\cos \theta)~d\theta=e^{-1}$

Tags: definite-integrals

In a work it was required to find an integral akin to  $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin 2 \theta~\tanh(\sin\theta) \tanh(\cos \theta)~d\theta.$$ Since $\tanh x$ and $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ are similar functions so it was a pleasure to see that its variant namely  $$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin 2\theta ~ \operatorname{erf}(\sin \theta)~ \operatorname{erf}(\cos \theta)~d\theta=e^{-1}$$
could be solved by Mathematica.

So the question is: Can one do it ($J$) by hand?

Comment: Where this integral comes from?

Comment: @Seewoo Lee  I have edited it, you  may see  how it came about.

Comment: It is easy to have a good *approximation* of *J* by hand using the series expansion of $\text{erf}(x)$ but I don't suppose that it could be an answer.

Comment: an interesting integral @DrZafar Ahmed DSc.

Comment: Another variation $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\sin(2x)erf(\cos x)erf(\sin x)dx=\frac{\pi}{4}e^{-1}$

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Yes, you are right but please see the question is for $J$ and not for $I$,  the proof for $I$ would be welcome and it will be bonus for us. In fact I had forgotten about $I$, until Seewoo Lee asked me a question here.

Comment: @Power Ranger Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The antiderivative can be found by hand.  Integrate by parts
$$\newcommand{\erf}{\operatorname{erf}}
\mathrm{d}u=\sin 2\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta,\quad v=\erf(\cos \theta)\erf(\sin \theta)
$$
gives
$$
-\frac12\cos 2\theta\erf(\sin \theta)\erf(\cos \theta)+
\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int\cos(2\theta)\left[e^{-\sin^2 \theta}\cos \theta\erf(\cos \theta)-e^{-\cos^2 \theta}\sin \theta\erf(\sin \theta)\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
Hence we are reduced to computing
$$
\int\cos(2\theta)\left[e^{-\sin^2 \theta}\cos \theta\erf(\cos \theta)-e^{-\cos^2 \theta}\sin \theta\erf(\sin \theta)\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
=e^{-1}\int\cos(2\theta)\left[e^{\cos^2 \theta}\cos \theta\erf(\cos \theta)-e^{\sin^2 \theta}\sin \theta\erf(\sin \theta)\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
But note that
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\left[e^{\cos^2 \theta}\sin \theta\erf(\cos \theta)\right]\\
&=(-2\sin \theta\cos \theta)e^{\cos^2 \theta}\sin \theta\erf(\cos \theta)
+e^{\cos^2 \theta}\cos \theta\erf(\cos \theta)
+e^{\cos^2 \theta}\sin \theta\frac2{\sqrt\pi}e^{-\cos^2 \theta}(-\sin \theta)\\
&=(-2\sin^2 \theta+1)e^{\cos^2 \theta}\cos \theta\erf(\cos \theta)
-\frac{2\sin^2 \theta}{\sqrt\pi}\\
&=\cos (2 \theta)e^{\cos^2 \theta}\cos \theta\erf(\cos \theta)
-\frac{2\sin^2 \theta}{\sqrt\pi}
\end{align*}
and the similar equation with $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ interchanged.
So putting these two together,
\begin{align*}
&\int\cos(2\theta)\left[e^{\cos^2 \theta}\cos \theta\erf(\cos \theta)-e^{\sin^2 \theta}\sin \theta\erf(\sin \theta)\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\left( e^{\cos^2 \theta} \erf(\cos \theta) \sin \theta - e^{\sin^2 \theta} \erf(\sin \theta) \cos \theta\right)+\int\frac2{\sqrt\pi}(\sin^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align*}
and of course you know how to do the final integral.

The final upshot is
\begin{align*}
&\int\sin(2\theta)\erf(\sin\theta)\erf(\cos\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac2{e\pi}\theta-\frac12\cos 2\theta\erf(\sin \theta)\erf(\cos \theta)\\
&\quad+\frac1{e\sqrt\pi}
\left( e^{\cos^2 \theta} \erf(\cos \theta) \sin \theta - e^{\sin^2 \theta} \erf(\sin \theta) \cos \theta\right)
\end{align*}

---

For $I$, this approach doesn't work, and I don't think there is a closd form solution to the definite integral.  However, we can express the MacLaurin series
$$
\tanh z=\sum_{k\geq 0} 2\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi^{2k+2}}\left(1-\frac1{4^{k+1}}\right)\zeta(2k+2)z^{2k+1}
$$
so
$$
I=4\sum_{k,k'\geq 0}(1-4^{-k-1})(1-4^{-k'-1})\frac{(-1)^{k+k'}\zeta(2k+2)\zeta(2k'+2)\Gamma(k+\frac12)\Gamma(k'+\frac12)}{\Gamma(k+k'+1)\pi^{2(k+k')+4}}
$$
which doesn't really simplify the task.

Comment: This is very surprising...(+1)

Comment: @User10354138 Your solution is amazing but there are typos which may spoil a general interest., for instance you are not carrying $1/\sqrt{\pi}$ after your first integration. Then, in the last equation $e^{-1}$ shouldn't be there. Also $\sin 2\theta$ is missing in the last equation. Your final answer is $e^{-1} \sqrt{\pi}$. You may edit your solution once.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc Where are you saying the missing $\sin 2\theta$ (in $I$?  That already went in the Beta function as $2\sin\theta\cos\theta$)?  And regarding the non-carrying of $1/\sqrt{\pi}$ that's the reason for taking it out of the integral so it doesn't waste space on my small screen.

Comment: @user10354138 I am bothering only about $J$ integral. In your last step I guess you are doing integration by parts taking $\cos 2 \theta$ as second function, then why $\frac{sin 2\theta }{2}$ is missing after the equality sign.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc No, the last step is to rewrite $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}[e^{\cos^2\theta}\sin\theta\operatorname{erf}(\cos\theta)]=\dots$ from the previous equation as $\int\dots\,\mathrm{d}\theta=e^{\cos^2\theta}\sin\theta\operatorname{erf}(\cos\theta)$ and combining with the unwritten one where $\sin$ and $\cos$ are interchanged in $e^{\cos^2\theta}\sin\theta\operatorname{erf}(\cos\theta)$.  There is no integration by parts there.

Answer (score 4):

$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin 2\theta  \mbox{erf}(\sin \theta) \mbox{erf}(\cos \theta). $$
I get clue from the fact that though $\tanh x$ and erf$(x)$ are similar, but the latter one enjoys beautiful expansions!
Expanding $$\mbox{erf}(x)= e^{-x^2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{\Gamma(n+3/2)}.$$ We re-write
$$J=2e^{-1}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{ \sin^{2m+2} \theta ~\ cos^{2n+2} \theta} {\Gamma(m+3/2)~\Gamma(n+3/2)} ~d \theta.$$
By Beta-integral, we get
$$J=e^{-1}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(m+n+2)}=e^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{(m+1)!}=e^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{(k+1)!}.$$
$$\Rightarrow e^{-1} \sum_{k=0} \left( \frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!} \right)=e^{-1}.$$