# The integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin (2x) ~ \tanh\left(2 \sin^2 x\right)~ \tanh\left(2\cos^2 x\right) ~dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Two integrals akin to $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin 2x~ \tanh(2 \sin^2 x) ~ \tanh(2\cos^2 x) ~dx$$
have been found interesting earlier

[The integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin 2\theta ~ \mbox{erf}(\sin \theta)~ \mbox{erf}(\cos \theta)~d\theta=e^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268231/the-integral-int-0-pi-2-sin-2-theta-mboxerf-sin-theta-mboxerf)

Mathematica does give the value of $I$. The question is how to get it by hand?

Comment: What did Mathematica give?

Comment: @Szeto  Oh! It is a bit lengthy expression.

Comment: @Szeto it gives $ (-1 - 3 e^4 + (1 + e^4) Log[1/2 (1 + e^4)])/(-1 + e^4)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\cos 2x=t$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin 2x \tanh(2 \sin^2 x) \tanh(2\cos^2 x) ~dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} \tanh(1-t) \tanh(1+t) dt.$$
Next, we use $\tanh 1=a$ and $\tanh t =z$, we get
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tanh^2 1-\tanh^2 t}{1-\tanh^2 1 \tanh^2 t} dt=(1+a^2)\int_{0}^{a} \frac{dz}{1-a^2z^2}-\int_{0}^{a} \frac{dz}{1-z^2}$$ $$=\frac{1+a^2}{a} \tanh^{-1} a^2-1.$$

Comment: Very snazzy (+1). much easier than I thought.

Comment: @clathratus , Thanks. they say that beauty lies in the eyes of the beholder.